# Serial port fails after some time

Tags: python, pi-3b+, serial, arduino

I use a RPi 3b to request and receive float values over serial from an Arduino Nano (fake). For that I use python and `pyserial`.

Arduino Loop:

```
if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    String req = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
    if (req == "co2") {
        double adjustedCO2 = myMHZ19.getCO2Raw();
        Serial.println(adjustedCO2, 2);}
    else if (req == "hum") {   
        Serial.println(bme.humidity);}
}
```

RPi Request:

```
def read_data(command): 
    req = command + "\n"
    ser.write(req.encode())
    line = ser.readline(100).decode('utf-8').rstrip()
    return float(line)
    
#main   
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600, timeout=1)
ser.flush()
time.sleep(2) #time to open up the serial connection
co2 = read_data("co2")
humidity = read_data("hum")
```

It works well for some time, but after a while (days/hours) my `read_data()` function returns only `None`. A reboot helps but I want to avoid that.

What am I missing? Do I need some timeouts? Is there a way to reset my serial port without rebooting?

Comment: It would be interesting to hear from people who voted to close, how did they deduce the problem was not Pi-specific.

Comment: To me it seemed like the pi was the problem. Because rebooting the pi helped temporarily while resetting the Arduino didn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to reset the serial port, by closing it and opening it again. This will also reset the Arduino.

However, I would rather try to understand what's wrong with the communication. You already have a timeout which should apply to all read/write operations.

Print raw strings (make sure you can distinguish strings with and without `\n`) which you send and receive from the UART inside `read_data()`. Then wait for the issue to happen and check how the communication looks on RPi side.

One thing I would try to avoid is using dynamic objects on Arduino. The `String req` object gets repeatedly created and destroyed, which could potentially result in memory fragmentation and lead to a situation where no new objects could be created until you reset. I'm not sure it's the root cause (`req` is tiny, even for Arduino) but it may be not the only dynamic object in your code.

Comment: I adjusted my Arduino Code accordingly. But the error was still there. Then I replaced the Arduino with a new one and now everything works again (for 2 days so far). I used the old one for half a year and requested data every minute. Could the dyn object or frequent request wear off my Arduinos serial port?

Comment: @Razorneck No, you can't "wear off" a serial port. You can have a buggy Arduino though, and it's possible that the bugs become more pronounced with age due to worse voltage stabilization for instance.